# Log4j2 with MemoryMappedFile and break files

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Is that possible to use MemoryMappedFile with Policies to break the files until fixed sizes, for example 250MB? My log4j2.xml is like this but I want to break the log files to 250MB and I need to use MemoryMappedFile for IO performance.

```
<Configuration monitorInterval="30">
    <Appenders>
        <MemoryMappedFile name="MemoryMap" fileName="output/jscsi-out.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] %c{2} - %m%n(%L)" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
            </Policies>
        </MemoryMappedFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="br.com" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="MemoryMap" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.jscsi.target.TargetServer" level="debug"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="MemoryMap" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.jscsi.target.storage" level="info"
            additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="MemoryMap" />
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="org.jscsi.service" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="MemoryMap" />
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="MemoryMap" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Both the memory mapped file and the rolling file appender extend the abstract output stream appender. You should be able to create a plugin that extends the abstract stream appender and basically copy and paste the functionality of both the mmap file and rolling file.

Answer (score 6):

(Background: I am the author of the MemoryMappedFile appender as well as Async Loggers.)

In some sense the MemoryMappedFile appender is still a work in progress (as of Log4j 2.5). As you mention, there is no Rolling variant. Also, I haven't been able to do any significant performance testing. I [made a start](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-930) some time ago but other issues took priority.

Initial performance testing indicates that synchronous logging, even when using the MemoryMappedFile appender, is unlikely to be faster than asynchronous logging via [Async Loggers](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html).

Generally, if you need the rollover behaviour I would suggest you use Async Loggers in combination with the RollingRandomAccessFile appender for now.

Comment: Currently I use Async Loggers in combination with the RollingRandomAccessFile appender. But I need to reduce HDD IO operations (e.g. avoid creating plain_log.txt: write to MemoryMappedFile or compress on the fly). What Is the easiest way to do it without writing hand-made plugins?

Comment: Compressing while logging is not supported by log4j. What’s the problem with Async Loggers + RandomAccessFile appender? That’s the setup that gives consistently high performance and I would recommend. MemoryMappedFile stuff can be slightly faster most of the time, and _a lot_ slower some of the time (especially remapping can take seconds).

Comment: The problem is that RollingRandomAccessFile writes the file to HDD, then read it, then compress and roll. Although we get significant performance with it in terms of CPU usage, but there is high IO percentage. The goal is to reduce it. Is it possible to modify some existing appender in order to keep  plain_log.txt in RAM instead of HDD, or add compress on the fly support?

Comment: Yes, you can increase the buffer size of the RandomAccessFile appender (see the user manual). But ultimately it sounds like the application is simply logging more than your operations people are comfortable with...